# Android Back Key

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

[image: Home Screen]

The logic continues as `Home Screen`->`Screen1`->`Screen2`->`Screen3`->`HomeScreen`.

1.On Pressing **Home Button** of `Screen3` it will return to `Home Screen`. Again On Pressing **Enter Button** of `Home Screen` it will goto `Screen1`then `Screen2`and `Screen3`.

2.Again now I'm on `Home Screen`. **If I Press back button it has to goto home screen of phone**. Instead, it's going in reverse order on pressing back key. I dont want to call `finish()` activity in each screen.

Give me a solution!

Comment: what android version are you targeting ?

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="16"

Comment: you can use the 'up' button. see http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Screen 3, override `onBackPressed()` and start Activity of HomeScreen with `Clear Top Flag`.

Here is the Sample

```
@Override
protected void onBackPressed()
{
   Intent i = new Intent(Screen3.this,HomeScreen.class);
   i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(i);
}
```